# C# RichTextBox + IrrlichtLime -> some keys are not working

Tags: c#, richtextbox, irrlicht

I am trying to use a combination of RichTexBox as a input file, which I am passing to Irrlicht engine through my interface. Problem is - when I successfully generate output, most keys on my keyboard are not working in RichTextBox. For example, Enter, Space, keys, Tab, Escape, Backspace are working, but numpad, all characters and so on are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem with a single workaround - when user clicks on Generate button, I render RichTextBox read only. When user clicks into RichTextBox or moves focus here, read only property turnes off and the whole Irrlicht device restarts into void status.

Comment: Maybe you use FPS camera in your scene. If so, you have to `setEventReceiverEnabled(false)` so it won't interfere with your RichTextBox.